# Crystal Reports Calculating a value from a summary total

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, calculation

I have a summary total in my report and dependent on the value it needs to return a value in days.  My solution would require updates if summary of days exceeds the last value entered in the formula.  Is there a calculation that should be used here?

Created an if then else formula in Crystal

IF Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID}) <= 2 THEN 0.5 ELSE
IF Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID}) <=  4 THEN 1.0 ELSE
IF Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID}) <=  6 THEN 1.5 ELSE
IF Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID}) <=  8 THEN 2.0 ELSE
IF Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID}) <=  10 THEN 2.5 ELSE............

This code requires many rows to be written and if the number increases the formula needs to change

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to round up to the nearest 0.5 after dividing by 4. You can simply use this expression:

```
Ceiling(Sum ({GALAXY_WORK_ORDER_OPERATION_DAYS.Days}, {WORK_ORDER_FACT.WORK_ORDER_ID})/4, 0.5)
```